# Replace string spaces with an underscore

Tags: c#, string, replace

I need to replace some spaces with an underscore (i.e. "PM HD PSP" > "PM_HD_PSP")

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
private string NombreExcel3(string excel)
{
    MessageBox.Show(excel);

    excel.Replace(' ','_');

    MessageBox.Show(excel);
    return excel;
}
```

Comment: You have to assign the result of `Replace` to a variable.

Comment: I think Replace have a return value. Did you try excel = excel.Replace(' ','_'); ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you need to do:

```
excel = excel.Replace(' ','_');
```

[String.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) wont alter the original string, it will instead return a *new* altered string.

> **String.Replace(): Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String.

Comment: and others were too slow =D

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment - how can I improve this answer?

Answer (score 4):

string.Replace(...) **returns** a new string object without modifying the original one

So you should do :

```
excel = excel.Replace(' ','_');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set excel to the replaced version.

```
excel = excel.Replace(' ','_');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
excel = excel.Replace(' ','_');
```

Replace does not change the string on place.

Comment: Thank you! that worked, missed that detail... will accept soon!